# ido, smex , candidates: show directories with different color

Tags: ido, smex

emacs 26.1 , windows 10, ido mode, smex package

```
M-x map
```

And here result:

[image]

smex show all candidates content text `map`
Nice. It's work fine.

But second candidates (`mappings`) is a directory. Rest of all candidates are files.

The question is: Is it possible separate (e.g. by text color) the directories and files candidates?

Comment: I think you are talking about 'ido-switch-buffer' function. Smex is for execute commands.